# Unable to upload large video size

Tags: php

Hi so I now have a working code which allows users to upload videos, however, it only works for small video sizes

the php code is:

```
<?php

require_once('../../../includes/config.php');

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {


    //collect form data

    extract($_POST);


    $allowedExts = array("ogg", "mp4", "wma");
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['video']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ((($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
        || ($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/ogg")
        || ($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/wma")

        && ($_FILES["video"]["size"] < 16000000 )
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))){ 


        if ($_FILES["video"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["video"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }


        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["video"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["video"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["video"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
           $upload =  $_FILES["video"]["name"];

            if (file_exists("../videos/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["video"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"],
                    "../videos/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "../videos/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"];
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo "Invalid file";
    }

            try {



                //insert into database

                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO videos (videoTitle,video,editedBy) VALUES (:videoTitle, :video, :editedBy)') ;

                $stmt->execute(array(

                    ':videoTitle' => $videoTitle,

                    ':video' => $upload,

                    ':editedBy' => "admin"



                ));



                //redirect to images page

                header('Location: videos.php?action=added');

                exit;



            } catch(PDOException $e) {

                echo $e->getMessage();

            }

}
?>
```

This works for files that are around 3000kb but when I tried to upload a video that was 200000 kb, it tried to do it for a while before I eventually get a "page cannot be reached".

Is there something I can do so it can cope with larger files? Is it possible to compress the file first so it's easier to handle?

I am using a free version of 000webhost so could this be due to a file size limit for uploading?

Thanks

Comment: Check your php.ini `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: unfortunately with 000webhost you can't see that file, although some searching it does appear that there is a 30mb limit with the free version, thanks for your help